# What can I do to resolve the conflict on binary with git subtree pull?

Tags: git, binary, git-merge

I am trying to `git subtree pull` and one of the binary file (in my case it is xls file) is conflicting.

I just wish to use whatever is available on remote, but I know git subtree pull does not have any argument like `--theirs`.

What can I do to resolve this issue?

`git mergetool` would not help me as much as it would for text snippet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not that familiar with `subtree`, but if it uses the index for merges the way git normally does, then after you get the merge conflict for `filename`, you can do:

```
git checkout --theirs /path/to/filename
git add /path/to/filename
```

And it will be resolved using the copy from the remote.